# Using Admob with Apache Cordova Phonegap and Javascript

Tags: mobile, cordova, admob

I have an app made with Phonegap and it runs on five platforms:
WebApp, Android, IOS, Blackberry and Windows Phone.

I would like to add ads to my app, so I started looking into AdMob.
Do they have a Javascript implementation that I could generically implement for all platforms or should I implement a native solution for each one?

I've looked into it but I couldn't find info on the subject.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Admob plugin and examples in the wild.  Personally, I wrestle with the same question myself with serving dfp ads on Mobile.  Knowing how to write plugins, I decided to go native plugin because I figured it would be better performance than serving it on the same page.  I also follow and use of those Admob plugin as example.

It wasn't too bad with Android LinearLayout, but iOS was a pain.  Especially when you have other native plugins that you have to position around the webview (top, bottom, etc...)  You have to handle plugin relocation whenever window resize, keyboard shrink view, etc...  But overall, it was a good learning experience.

But anyway, even though Admob can be serve on a web page with javascript, I believe your only answer is native plugin.  This is because it might be violating the TOS "If we determine that an AdMob account might pose a risk to our advertisers, we may disable that account to protect our advertisers' interests. "

Comment: Thanks, I'm going with native AdMob implementation for the apps and AdSense for the WebApp.